# Matlab - Data Cursor "step" too big

Tags: matlab

I plot some Bode diagrams in Matlab and I have problem with Data Cursor. If I look at phase, when I move Data Cursor, I can go for example from 170 degrees to 176 degrees, but I can't go from 170 degrees to 171 degrees. So "step" of Data cursor is too big. Is there way to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved :) Selection style should be set to Mouse position instead of Snap to nearest data vertex

Comment: you can add this as an answer and accept it! It will probably help future readers!

Answer (score 1):

Solved :) Selection style should be set to Mouse position instead of Snap to nearest data vertex

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the data point and change the selection style to mouse position